# Image cropping with fixed aspect ratio

Tags: php, crop, image-resizing

I'm trying to take in two sets of x-y co-ordinates from an image in a 7:9 aspect ratio and replace the original image with the cropped section in a 280x360 image, but it's not working. It's not throwing up any errors but the image replacement after cropping doesn't seem to work. Echoing data tells me it takes in everything up to the imagecopyresampled code.

```
$formDatax1=$_POST["x1"];
$formDatax2=$_POST["x2"];
$formDatay1=$_POST["y1"];
$formDatay2=$_POST["y2"];

$filename='http://pathtofiles/path/photo/'.$a_photo;

$image_info = getimagesize($filename);

switch(strtolower($image_info['mime'])){
case 'image/png' : $image = imagecreatefrompng($filename); $imgtype='png'; break;
case 'image/jpeg': $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); $imgtype='jpg'; break;
case 'image/gif' : $image = imagecreatefromgif($filename); $imgtype='gif'; break;
default: die();
}

$resized_width = ((int)$formDatax2) - ((int)$formDatax1);
$resized_height = ((int)$formDatay2) - ((int)$formDatay1);

$resized_image = imagecreatetruecolor(280, 360);
imagecopyresampled($resized_image, $image, 0, 0, (int)$formDatax1, (int)$formDatay1, 280, 360, $resized_width, $resized_height);

if ($imgtype=='png') {
    imagepng($resized_image, $filename);
}

if ($imgtype=='jpg') {
    imagejpeg($resized_image, $filename);
}

if ($imgtype=='gif') {
    imagejpeg($resized_image, $filename);
}

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Image cropped!"); </script>';
exit();
```

Comment: var_dump returns bool(true), there is no output image or it's not overwriting the original image.

Comment: Thanks to miken32 below, changing from an absolute path to a relative path seems to work, adding $filename='photo/'.$a_photo; before the last if checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not specifying a new value for `$filename`. The [http[s] URL wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) can retrieve a file, but not write. You'll need to specify a local filesystem location to save the image to.

Comment: I'm trying to overwrite the original image.

Comment: How do you expect to overwrite this? `$filename='http://pathtofiles/path/photo/'.$a_photo;`

Comment: That's not the actual path, just a placeholder. $a_photo is the filename. I use the full path in the live code.

Comment: And it's a filesystem location? No http?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the images, image folder and PHP script are all on the same server. I could just use /photo/'.$a_photo; but would that make a difference?

Comment: Retrieving a file via http is completely different than retrieving it from the local file system. I would hope you don't open your entire hard drive to write access from the internet!

Answer (score 0):

**This solution is from PHP cookbook 3rd edition**

Use the ImageCopyResampled() function, scaling the image as needed.
To shrink proportionally:

```
$filename = __DIR__ . '/php.png';
$scale = 0.5; // Scale
// Images
$image = ImageCreateFromPNG($filename);
$thumbnail = ImageCreateTrueColor(
ImageSX($image) * $scale,
ImageSY($image) * $scale);
// Preserve Transparency
ImageColorTransparent($thumbnail,
ImageColorAllocateAlpha($thumbnail, 0, 0, 0, 127));
ImageAlphaBlending($thumbnail, false);
ImageSaveAlpha($thumbnail, true);
// Scale & Copy
ImageCopyResampled($thumbnail, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0,
ImageSX($thumbnail), ImageSY($thumbnail),
ImageSX($image), ImageSY($image));
// Send
header('Content-type: image/png');
ImagePNG($thumbnail);
ImageDestroy($image);
ImageDestroy($thumbnail);
```

To shrink to a fixed-size rectangle:

```
// Rectangle Version
$filename = __DIR__ . '/php.png';
// Thumbnail Dimentions
$w = 50; $h = 20;
// Images
$original = ImageCreateFromPNG($filename);
$thumbnail = ImageCreateTrueColor($w, $h);
// Preserve Transparency
ImageColorTransparent($thumbnail,
ImageColorAllocateAlpha($thumbnail, 0, 0, 0, 127));
ImageAlphaBlending($thumbnail, false);
ImageSaveAlpha($thumbnail, true);
// Scale & Copy
$x = ImageSX($original);
$y = ImageSY($original);
$scale = min($x / $w, $y / $h);
ImageCopyResampled($thumbnail, $original,
0, 0, ($x - ($w * $scale)) / 2, ($y - ($h * $scale)) / 2,
$w, $h, $w * $scale, $h * $scale);
// Send
header('Content-type: image/png');
ImagePNG($thumbnail);
ImageDestroy($original);
ImageDestroy($thumbnail);
```

Comment: A quick look at the code will tell you he's calling the functions properly and probably doesn't need a complicated tutorial copied and pasted from a book.